# speed of fprintf() vs. fwrite()

Tags: c, performance, printf, fwrite

I have seen it stated in several places that an fprintf() operation is a bit slower that an fwrite() operation, due to the extra formatting operations in fprintf. I wanted to see if I could actually test this so I have some sample code below which (I believe) does just that.
results are of course always a little different, however the majority of the time they are something like this:

Avg. no. of ticks per fwrite() over 1000000 writes: 0.2000

Avg. no. of ticks per fprintf() over 1000000 writes: 0.1300

i.e. fwrite() seems to be actually a little bit slower that fprintf().
So my question here is two-fold:

A. looking at the code (below) I used to test this, is this a reasonable method to test
      such a thing? can anyone speculate wether the results it yields are in anyway way an
      accurate representation of how long each operation actually takes (in terms of 
      ticks)?

B. If so, why is it that fwrite() takes longer when I would assume that fprintf() has
      effectively more work with the formatting?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NO_OF_WRITES 1000000

int main()
{
    clock_t start1, end1, start2, end2;
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    float avg;
    float diffs = 0;
    uint8_t byte = 0x30;

    if ((fp = fopen("file.bin", "w")) == NULL)
    {
            printf("Error opening file for writing");
            exit(-1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_WRITES; i++)
    {
            start1 = clock();
            fwrite(&byte, 1, 1, fp);
            end1 = clock();

            diffs += (end1 - start1);
    }

    avg = diffs / NO_OF_WRITES;
    printf("Avg. no. of ticks per fwrite() over %d writes: %.4f\n", NO_OF_WRITES, avg);

    diffs = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_WRITES; i++)
    {
            start2 = clock();
            fprintf(fp, "%c", byte);
            end2 = clock();

            diffs += (end2 - start2);
    }

    avg = diffs / NO_OF_WRITES;
    printf("Avg. no. of ticks per fprintf() over %d writes: %.4f\n", NO_OF_WRITES, avg);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: I think I would put the clock time capturing outside the for loop, but that's just me!

Comment: It is an OK way to test such a thing, but the times for different ammount of data and different sizes of the file are differents. Nether nessisarily flushes the stream when it is done. Both are highly dependent on the hardware and OS, so you'd have to take many full runs to get a real number.

Comment: I agree with trumpetlicks that you should time the entire loop not each iteration. Also, you should ensure that the conditions are the same for each test. Delete the file, open it, write to it and close it for each test.

Comment: @trumpetlicks To expand why this is important, your average number for writing a single byte is LESS THAN 1 tick. This means you are trying to "measure" something less than the size you can. For comparison, imaging you have a ruler that only has 0 and 1 ft on it. You're trying to measure 2 inches :-P.

Comment: Your question `B` depends on a number of things including platform, compiler version, and possibly even hardware. If you really want the answer you should include this information in your post.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams - Im actually not sure what you're saying is completely correct.  File operations are extremely slow in relativity to the clocking of the CPU.  In fact there may be multiple ticks just to put the byte out on the bus to actually be written, then for the drive it is being written to, to answer back.  Usually this is why we try to write files in batches of multiple bytes, instead of a byte at a time, because under the hood, that will look like one actual setup and transfer time for th lot, instead of multiple.

Comment: In addition to everything said about timing, take care that you are really testing what you think you test. My compiler (gcc) converts `printf("%c", c)` to `putchar(c)`, which is probably the fastest way to write a char. (That's without explicit optimisation, i.e `-O0`)

Comment: @trumpetlicks Actually writing to the harddrive is slower, but my first comment was that the file doesn't necessarily get written when you make this call. It tells the OS "Hey write this", which typically gets copied to a stream buffer and written when either the files stream is flushed (using fflush) or closed (edit: or when the OS feels like it).  His/her own measurements are at 0.2 and 0.13 ticks :-/.

Comment: wow some very quick answers there.... MadScienceDreams that's a good idea, I'll make some changes along the lines of suggestion made by Jim Rhodes, move the clock capture outside the for loop (thanks trumpetlicks) and perhaps write 1024 bytes instead of 1.

Comment: `%c` is about the simplest formatting you can do. Try instead formatting double-precision, like `15.5g`. And put the clocks outside the loop.

Comment: let me widen the scope here.... The end goal here is to use either fwrite() or fprint() to write GPIO values to sysfs files on a linux board.
So in this situation I'd only be writing a char '0' or '1'. It's starting to look like, when only writing one byte like this, the difference in speed is almost nothing or at least negligible.

However out of curiosity I will continue to investigate, using the helpful suggestions you fine folks have provided here....

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: Using floating point formatting is not a legitimate comparison either since `fwrite` can't do that. The situation where both `fwrite` and `fprintf` would be viable solutions is for writing strings. Compare calls to `fwrite(str,strlen(str),1,f)` with calls to `fprintf(f,"%s",str)` for some reasonable-size strings.

Comment: @ErikNyquist: If you're writing single bytes at a time, both are horribly slow. You should be using `putc`.

Comment: I think that `fwrite` and `fprintf` are two different functions for different tasks. `fwrite` writes contiguous chunks of data of known size to the disk; I associate it with binary files. `fprintf` writes human-readable data; I associate it with text files. So in my opinion you're comparing apples with oranges.

Comment: Both can be used with either text or binary mode.

Comment: @R..: Yes, but still they're not the same. When I distinguished between binary and text in my comment, I didn't mean the mode in which the file was opened, but the nature of the data to write. In a real application I think it's pretty clear which of the two to use; I'd also be surprised to see calls of `fprintf` and `fwrite` mixed in client code for writing to the same file. The OP is comparing two corner cases of both functions, which are essentially a fancy alternative to `putc`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're testing writes of a single character, it is likely that other overhead is dominating.  In particular, `fwrite` takes two arguments that it multiplies together to determine the total size to write, and it is likely that that single multiply instruction is dominating the time needed by `fwrite`...

Answer (score 0):

http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/02/07/speed-tests-fprintf-vs-ofstream-and-fprintf-vs-fwrite/

I think this would solve your problem

Comment: I have a major argument with the test on this link. He's doing an fflush (or equivalent) after every fwrite/fprintf/out. This means that the time measurement of these calls in being dwarfed by the I/O overhead of flushing the buffers. The conclusions are probably correct (fwrite is faster then fprintf is faster than out), the the magnitude of the differences is wrong!

Comment: I just ran this on my macbook M2 ventura, 5M reps, omit fflush,
running snprintf on every loop iteration:
fprintf() took 1.0211 seconds
fwrite() took 0.96121 seconds
fwrite faster 1.0623x
running snprintf only once before loop:
fprintf() took 0.085335 seconds
fwrite() took 0.0677694 seconds
fwrite faster 1.2592x
fwrite sans snprintf, faster 11.9658x
fprintf sans snprintf, faster 14.1835x